# Deprecated permission message

Tags: deprecated

Have been seeing this message recently quite a lot in our drupal log. Anything we need to worry about?

```
[PHP User Deprecation] Permission 'administer CiviDiscount' should be declared with 'label' and 'description' keys. See                                                                 [notice]
https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_permission/ Caller: CRM_Core_Permission::assembleBasicPermissions Error.php:1129 [4.61 sec, 94.5 MB]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a warning message for now but soon it will be a fatal error or permission won't respected if not handled as per coding standards.

The above warning is from [Civi Discount](https://civicrm.org/extensions/cividiscount) extension and it has been [fixed](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/cividiscount/-/merge_requests/306) recently.

You can either apply the [patch](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/cividiscount/-/merge_requests/306.patch) or wait for a release.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: thank you for your prompt response, will ask our developer to patch and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: The patch worked for us, thank you so much for your help